# "Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module when running Jasmine tests"

Tags: node.js, webpack, jasmine, node-modules, jasmine-node

I'm facing an issue while running Jasmine tests for my project. When I execute the command jasmine in my project directory, I encounter the following error:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\faris\Desktop\KODING\DICODING\dicoding-expert-3\src\scripts\utils\like-button-initiator' imported from C:\Users\faris\Desktop\KODING\DICODING\dicoding-expert-3\specs\sampleTestSpec.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:326:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:945:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

I have already added `"type": "module"` in my **package.json** file to enable ES modules. The file **like-button-initiator** is located at the specified path *'C:\Users\faris\Desktop\KODING\DICODING\dicoding-expert-3\src\scripts\utils\like-button-initiator'*, and the test file **sampleTestSpec.js** imports it.

I have tried different solutions, such as verifying the file path, reinstalling dependencies, and confirming that the file exists. However, the error persists.

Can someone please help me understand the cause of this error and suggest a possible solution? Thank you!

I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

1. Added `"type": "module"` to my `package.json` file to enable ES modules.
2. Verified the file path of `like-button-initiator` located at `'C:\Users\faris\Desktop\KODING\DICODING\dicoding-expert-3\src\scripts\utils\like-button-initiator'`.
3. Reinstalled project dependencies.
4. Confirmed that the `like-button-initiator` file exists at the specified path.
5. Ensured that the `sampleTestSpec.js` file correctly imports `like-button-initiator`.

I was expecting the Jasmine tests to run successfully without encountering the `ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error. However, despite taking these steps, the error persists. I'm looking for insights or alternative solutions to resolve this issue. Thank you!